# Applying multiple shadows for text object kineticjs

Tags: kineticjs

There are possibility to use multiple shadows in css - http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/text-shadow/demo/index.html.

I want to do the same in kineticjs (neon effect).
But according to docs, i can apply only one shadow to object.

Is there a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that in 3 steps:

1. Create your neon text on an offscreen html canvas -- document.createElement("canvas") ...
2. Convert that canvas to an image object using newImage.src=myCanvas.toDataURL().
3. Use that image object to create a Kinetic.Image

Here's a link to a post on how to create neon text in html canvas:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/texteffects/